# d3 javascript loop through array of data objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

Say I have an Array of these objects:

```
[
{name: "P1", Subj1: 9.7, Subj2: 10, Subj3: 9.5, Subj4: 8.2, Subj5:9.3,         Subj6: 8.9},
{name: "P2", Subj1: 9.7, Subj2: 10, Subj3: 9.5, Subj4: 8.2, Subj5:9.3,     Subj6: 8.9},
{name: "P3", Subj1: 9.7, Subj2: 10, Subj3: 9.5, Subj4: 8.2, Subj5:9.3, Subj6: 8.9} ]
```

I would like to plot a bar chart for one person. I currently have this code:

```
d3.select("#chart").selectAll("div.h-bar")
        .data(getObj(name))
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "h-bar")
        .append("span");

        //delete elements not associated with data element
        d3.select("#chart").selectAll("div.h-bar")
        .data(getObj(name))
        .exit().remove();


        d3.select("#chart").selectAll("div.h-bar") 
        .data(getObj(name))
        .attr("class", "h-bar")
        .style("width", function (d) {


            return ( d.Subj1* 10) + "px";



        }

        )
        .select("span")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });
```

with the getObj(name) function:

function getObj(Name){

```
        for(var i = 0; i <studentList.length; i++){
            if(studentList[i].Naam == Name){


                console.log(studentList[i]);
                return [studentList[i]];


            }
        }
    }
```

I cant figure out how to get a bar chart for person 1 where every bar has a width of achieved note, and the span text the name of the subject.

Any hints?

Comment: is .Naam supposed to be .name?

Comment: I changed the language so it would be easier to understand, problem stays the same.